# When select file size return 0 on cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing mobile app using cordova, ionic 1 and angular 1. I choose file in my application with input file type, but file size sometimes return 0. How can i fix this problem.

```js
angular.element('#fileInput').on('change', function (event) {
  console.log(event.target.files[0].size);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" class=“fileInput"/>
```

**EDIT:**

**Step 1:** I choose file with input[type=“file”] from Google drive, Dropbox or iCloud.

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" class=“fileInput"/>
```

[ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9c1S.png)

**Step 2:** I'm converting file to base64 string. (Actually my problem is here. As i said, file size sometimes return 0. But just sometimes) (event.target.files[0].size)

```
angular.element('#fileInput').on('change', function (event) {
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
      var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
      $scope.base64FileData = btoa(binaryString);
   }

   reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

[ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKmkL.png)

**Step 3:** I'm sending Base64 string to other users with XMPP.

Comment: Are you using any of the file related plugins for cordova? Are you using any of the NgCordova wrappers?

Comment: i am just using input[type="file"]

Comment: That's your issue. JavaScript does not have access to file size information on the device without using a cordova plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file There's also an ngCordova Wrapper for that plugin at ngcordova.com.

Comment: i must select file in google drive or dropbox. How can i do this with cordova file plugin?

Comment: I don't think you've given us all the information we need to solve your problem, as more keeps coming out the more we talk.

Comment: OK then, let’s go step by step. I edited post.

Comment: What Cordova plugins are you using and what version are they? Out of the box your mobile app shouldn't have access to the action center.